# Adding Mac OS X app to "General Services"

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have found that "Services..." a very useful place to add functionality via AppleScript.

[image]

I have written a small OS X app that uploads documents to a web based service (it requires OAuth2) and thought it would be great to add this functionality to the "Services" submenu. For example, when I am viewing a pdf in Preview to upload directly from a Services item.

I have tried wading through Apple's documentation on "Services", but I don't see how to add one outside of the Automator. I would be happy to use that but:

1. Do I need to make my app AppleScript-able? If so, how?
2. Is there another way to add Services outside of the Automator?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add a new target `Automator action` to your project to expose the functionality to Automator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript/Automator are not needed, there's a couple steps involved (Info.plist entry and handler in your app). See the [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-BABDICBI) for details.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I kept ending up in a different "Services" place. The guide listed above what just what I was looking for. Before I ask another question, do you happen to know how to get the name/path of document that I am looking at (say in Preview) onto a NSPasteboard? I have already implemented a drag-and-drop which works fine, but ideally I would like to capture the Preview document path with a system Services command. I can see strings that have been cut or copied, but don't see how it is possible to get the path onto a pasteboard.

Comment: Hmm not sure it's possible. If I have PDF files open in Preview, my Services menu just shows "No Services Apply". Whereas if I highlight a file in the Finder, it shows a whole bunch that apply to files.